# Error from alx network driver since installing new SSD drive

Tags: hard-drive, pcie

Yesterday I added a new 1TB SATA SSD (Seagate 120)

I see in the logs since yesterday that I have an error happening over and over.  Google searching for this error generally people say "use a kerrnel setting to suppress it" but I cannot confirm that in my case it is exactly the same.

```
Mar 22 07:50:24 komp kernel: [ 2451.204660] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
Mar 22 07:50:24 komp kernel: [ 2451.204872] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Mar 22 07:50:24 komp kernel: [ 2451.204880] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:   device [1969:e0a1] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
Mar 22 07:50:24 komp kernel: [ 2451.204886] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:    [ 7] BadDLLP                
Mar 22 07:50:24 komp kernel: [ 2451.205132] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
Mar 22 07:50:24 komp kernel: [ 2451.205583] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
Mar 22 07:50:29 komp kernel: [ 2456.213360] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
Mar 22 07:50:29 komp kernel: [ 2456.213440] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Mar 22 07:50:29 komp kernel: [ 2456.213448] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:   device [1969:e0a1] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Mar 22 07:50:29 komp kernel: [ 2456.213454] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                  
Mar 22 07:50:29 komp kernel: [ 2456.214389] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
Mar 22 07:50:29 komp kernel: [ 2456.214477] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Mar 22 07:50:29 komp kernel: [ 2456.214485] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:   device [1969:e0a1] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
Mar 22 07:50:29 komp kernel: [ 2456.214490] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:    [ 7] BadDLLP                
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.213381] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.213442] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.213449] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:   device [1969:e0a1] error status/mask=00000040/00002000
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.213454] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:    [ 6] BadTLP                 
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.213763] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.214132] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.214136] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:   device [1969:e0a1] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.214140] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:    [ 7] BadDLLP                
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.214410] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.214830] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.214938] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.214942] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:   device [1969:e0a1] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.214945] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:    [ 7] BadDLLP                
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.215697] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.215814] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.215821] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:   device [1969:e0a1] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.215825] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:    [ 7] BadDLLP                
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.217799] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.217930] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.217939] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:   device [1969:e0a1] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
Mar 22 07:50:32 komp kernel: [ 2459.217946] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:    [ 7] BadDLLP                
Mar 22 07:50:33 komp kernel: [ 2460.209405] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
Mar 22 07:50:33 komp kernel: [ 2460.209472] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Mar 22 07:50:33 komp kernel: [ 2460.209480] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:   device [1969:e0a1] error status/mask=00000081/00002000
Mar 22 07:50:33 komp kernel: [ 2460.209485] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                  
Mar 22 07:50:33 komp kernel: [ 2460.209489] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:    [ 7] BadDLLP                
Mar 22 07:50:34 komp kernel: [ 2461.204259] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
Mar 22 07:50:34 komp kernel: [ 2461.204404] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Mar 22 07:50:34 komp kernel: [ 2461.204412] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:   device [1969:e0a1] error status/mask=00000040/00002000
Mar 22 07:50:34 komp kernel: [ 2461.204417] alx 0000:03:00.0: AER:    [ 6] BadTLP
```

from lspci it appears to be comming from the Gigabit ethernet controller.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a336 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5003 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

The errors started only since I installed the new 1TB drive, but before I even formatted it - The drive was only paritioned and formatted several hours later.

I don't know what the errors mean.  The drive appears to work OK and I'm not noticing anything else wrong besides the errors showing in the logs.

What could this mean?  I am hoping for something like a BIOS setting to resolve a conflict... but don't have very high hopes.  I have really not worked much on PC hardware or BIOS'es in the last 15 years or so.

The computer is an MSI GP63 Leopard 8RE running KDE Neon 5.18

johan@komp:~$ uname -a

```
Linux komp 5.3.0-42-generic #34~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 13:42:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

EDIT:
 1. As per the comment below, the error is picked up by the alx driver.  But the alx and the new drive could share a bus so that is not 100% certain.
 2. The error started when I powered up after installing the new drive. But there COULD have been a latent issue that I wasn't aware of, such as a driver or kernel that had been installed but not rebooted since, before the new drive was installed.  I do not reboot often.
 3. I just did a test with using the wired network port, which I don't use often.  The error rate goes up a lot up when there is data going through the network.  The error rate remains absolutely constant when using the new drive - this looks like a scheduled polling.
 4. It looks like that the error disappears when I sleep (suspend) but then starts again on the next reboot.  This could have hidden the error for a long time, as I may have never looked at the logs at the right moment.

All of the above puts some doubt on whether this is actually the new drive orjust a co-incidence.

Comment: `alx` is a driver for ethernet controller, could be from that.

Comment: The `lspci` also shows that the PCI node is the gigabit ethernet controller.  But the co-incidence is too high - this only happens since installing the new SSD drive.  Opening this laptop is a royal pain too, so removing the drive to go back to the previous configuration would be frustrating.